# How can I manage multiple seasons in a Vimeo On-demand page?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

According to the [Vimeo API documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start), it is possible to retrieve a list of season objects for a single On-demand page. However, there doesn't appear to be a way to create multiple seasons per page, either via the API or Vimeo's management dashboard.

It appears that when an On-demand page is created, a single season is automatically created in it and all videos belong to that season. However, [this On-Demand page from the BBC](https://vimeo.com/ondemand/sherlockseries) has multiple seasons, and indeed, when you [query it with the API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/ondemand/pages/sherlockseries/seasons) it returns multiple season objects.

How can additional seasons be defined for a single On-Demand page?